# Cannot find symbol java error

Tags: java, class, variables, symbols

I'm relatively new to java and programming. I am attempting to write a program for an assignment given to me. However, I am getting the following error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: variable carMake
location: class CarTransferClient
```

This error is given for each of the variables in the following line of code:

```
System.out.println("Result = " + carTransfer(carMake, carModel, carEngine, carPetrolDiesel, location, destination, distance));
```

This is the full code for the section that I am attempting to write:

```
public class CarTransferClient {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Result = " + carTransfer(carMake, carModel, carEngine, carPetrolDiesel, location, destination, distance));
    }

    private static String carTransfer(java.lang.String carMake, java.lang.String carModel, java.lang.String carEngine, java.lang.String carPetrolDiesel, java.lang.String location, java.lang.String destination, java.lang.String distance) {
        webservices.CarTransfer_Service service = new webservices.CarTransfer_Service();
        webservices.CarTransfer port = service.getCarTransferPort();
        return port.carTransfer(carMake, carModel, carEngine, carPetrolDiesel, location, destination, distance);
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong and how can it be fixed?

I was given the following working code as an example if it helps:

```
public class ConvertClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Result = " + feetToMetres(1));
}

private static String feetToMetres(double feet) {
        webservices.Convert_Service service = new webservices.Convert_Service();
        webservices.Convert port = service.getConvertPort();
        return port.feetToMetres(feet);
}
}
```

Comment: if you want to call String literals like you intended here, you have to put in quotes like so: `carTransfer("carMake", "carModel", "carEngine", "carPetrolDiesel", "location", "destination", "distance")`. Or you instantiate these variables and give them String values. Also, for simplicity/readability sake, you don't have to invoke String with the package (`java.lang.String`), just `String` is fine

Comment: @Maljam Thanks for the quick reply. However, I don't think this is correct. I have added a working example that I was given to the post if this helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `carMake`, `carModel`, etc in the System.out is looking for variables named `carMake`, `carModel`. You need to declare them before making the call.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String carMake = "Make";
    String carModel = "Model";
    String carEngine= = "Engine";
    String carPetrolDiesel = "Diesel";
    String location = "Location";
    String destination = "Destination";
    String distance = "Distance";

    System.out.println("Result = " + carTransfer(carMake, carModel, carEngine, carPetrolDiesel, location, destination, distance));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, I don't think this is correct. I have added a working example that I was given to the post if this helps?

Comment: What do you mean, "I don't think this is correct". Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the print method `System.out.println()` you have to give it **valid arguments**. Those arguments, in your case, must be `String` variables that have been instantiated or string literals which look like this `"string literal example"`.

You cannot send the method or any method for that matter, a variable that the program "doesn't know about".

Here is an example of a `String` variable (or `String` object) `String name = "fred";` and fred would be the string literal.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, I don't think this is correct. I have added a working example that I was given to the post if this helps?

Comment: yes I said in your case you must send it a String literal or String object variable. but i did leave you you can send it other primitive type literals or variables such as int, float, double etc.

Comment: in the working example you supplied, the method `feetToMetres(1)` RETURNS `returns feet` (which is a reference to an int). which is a valid argument for the print() method

Comment: it would also help to know what you are trying to do. it also seems like you are returning a method call, and will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that there are no vars for carMake, carModel etc.
    carTransfer(carMake, carModel, carEngine, carPetrolDiesel, location, destination, distance)
With this, you basically told java to looking for var that called `carMake`, `carModel` etc but you didn't initialize those vars, they doesn't exist. If you want to pass a string, do it using the "-sign. for example:

```
 System.out.println("Result = " + carTransfer("Make", "some model", "some engine", "some petrol diesel", "some location", "some destination", "some distance"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, I don't think this is correct. I have added a working example that I was given to the post if this helps?

Comment: did you try my answer or you just think that this isn't correct? If you tried my answer and still got an error, is it the same? if not - can you paste me the error here please?